# Percentage of 2 @@RowCounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get the Percentage of these two tables row count. Ideally I would like just to see the percentage and nothing else.

This is what I have tried with no luck.

```
Select Distinct ID
from dbo.1
Where StartDate between '2014-04-01' and '2017-04-30'
and Status  = 'ATTENDED'
order by ID

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Rowcount1'


Select Distinct ID
from dbo.1
Where Acitve = 'Y'
and StartDate between '2014-04-01' and '2017-04-30'
and Status = 'ATTENDED'
order by EmrID

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS 'RowCount2'

SELECT 'RowCount1' / 'RowCount2' AS Percentage
```

Comment: Saving the row counts in variables and multiplying by 100 would get you closer to a percentage. You may still want to use `cast` or `convert` to avoid integer division. In any event SqlZim's or Gordon Linoff's answers make far more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need `select distinct`, then SQLZim's answer is correct.  If you do, then you need to tweak the answer.  Here is one way:

```
select count(*) as RowCount
       count(distinct case when Active = 'Y' then id end) as ActiveCount,
       count(distinct case when Active = 'Y' then id end) * 1.0 / count(distinct id) 
from dbo.1
where StartDate >= '2014-04-01' and StartDate <= '2017-04-30' and
      Status = 'ATTENDED';
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you trying to use `@@rowcount` like that? How about some conditional aggregation instead?

```
select 
    AllCount    = count(*)
  , ActiveCount = count(case when Active='Y' then 1 end)
  , Percentage  = avg(case when Active='Y' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
from dbo.t
where StartDate >= '2014-04-01' 
  and StartDate <= '2017-04-30'
  and Status = 'ATTENDED'
```

Also, be careful with `between`. [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want percent try this:

```
SELECT 
       ( 
              SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, Count(DISTINCT id))
              FROM   dbo.1 
              WHERE  startdate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND    '2017-04-30' 
              AND    status = 'ATTENDED') / 
       ( 
              SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, count(DISTINCT id))
              FROM   dbo.1 
              WHERE  acitve = 'Y' 
              AND    startdate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND    '2017-04-30' 
              AND    status = 'ATTENDED') AS percentage
```

If you also want the individual values try this:

```
DECLARE @val1 INT;
DECLARE @val2 INT;

SELECT @val1 = Count(DISTINCT id) 
FROM   dbo.1 
WHERE  startdate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND    '2017-04-30' 
AND    status = 'ATTENDED'

SELECT @val2 = count(DISTINCT id) 
FROM   dbo.1 
WHERE  acitve = 'Y' 
AND    startdate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND    '2017-04-30' 
AND    status = 'ATTENDED'

SELECT @val1 AS val1, @val2 AS val2, CONVERT(FLOAT, @val1) / CONVERT(FLOAT, @val2) AS percent
```

The order by statements aren't needed as all you care about is the counts.

This can be reduced using a CTE too:

```
;WITH

base AS (
    SELECT id, acitve
    FROM   dbo.1 
              WHERE  startdate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND    '2017-04-30' 
              AND    status = 'ATTENDED'
)

SELECT 
       ( 
              SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, Count(DISTINCT id))
              FROM   base) / 
       ( 
              SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, count(DISTINCT id))
              FROM   base
              WHERE  acitve = 'Y') AS percentage
```